# Visual Studio Code IDE | Cucumber | Any possible way to navigate to Step definition file from the feature file (like in Ruby Mine IDE)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cucumber

I have been a RubyMine IDE and now I am trying to use VS Code IDE. I want to navigate from the feature file to the step definition. I tried multiple extensions like Cucumber (Gherkin) Full Support, etc but none of them work properly. I always get redirected to one of the step definition files (as if it is set as a default step definition) if I click on any of the steps from the feature file. How to deal with this? Any other extension which is recommended to use?

Thank you.

Comment: you can try [BDD Goto Step](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-bdd-gotostep), if it does not work create an issue with example step and feature and I will modify the extension

Answer (score 0):

I think your .vscode\settings.json is not good...

**My setup:**
In VSCode, add "Cucumber (Gherkin) Full Support - Alexander Krechik"
Note, in my case, doN'T install "Cucumber - Cucumber"!

CMD/PowerShell:

```
md newfolder
cd newfolder
dotnet new -i specflow.templates.dotnet
dotnet new specflowproject --help
dotnet new specflowproject -f net5.0 -t nunit
```

**Now the actual solution...**
Create .vscode\settings.json, some thing like:

```
{
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
        "/**/Steps/**/*.cs"
    ]
}
```

F12 and Ctrl+mouse click should to work well.